# tengo problemas con mi js

Tags: javascript, html

un cordial saludo para todos.
estoy creando en HTML y JavaScript una pagina sencilla donde pueda agregar y borrar notas, las cuales se puede presentar en la vida cotidiana, al momento de ejecutar el JavaScript de crear una nueva nota no lo esta haciendo y en la consola no muestra error alguno, las notas que están creadas por defecto en el HTML se pueden eliminar pero si requiero agregar una nota nueva me aparece las que están por defecto, y no he encontrado el error de la lógica.
soy principiante en esta vida de la programación.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const crearNota = document.getElementById('crearNota');
    const misNotas = document.getElementById('misNotas');
    const listaNotas = document.getElementById('listaNotas');

    crearNota.addEventListener('click', function () {
        const notaText = misNotas.value.trim();

        if (notaText !== '') {
            const nota = document.createElement('div');
            nota.classList.add('nota');

            const notaTexto = document.createElement('span');
            notaTexto.textContent = notaText;

            const eliminar = document.createElement('button');
            eliminar.classList.add('eliminar');
            eliminar.textContent = 'Borrar';

            nota.appendChild(notaTexto);
            nota.appendChild(eliminar);

            listaNotas.appendChild(nota);

            misNotas.value = '';
        }
    });

    listaNotas.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target.classList.contains('eliminar')) {
            const nota = e.target.parentElement;
            listaNotas.removeChild(nota);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Proyecto Final</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Mis Notas</h1>
        <form id="notaForm">
            <input id="misNotas" placeholder="Algo para recordar"></input>
            <button id="createButton">Crear</button>
        </form>

        <div id="listaNotas">
            <div class="nota">
                <span>Mi Primera Nota</span>
                <button class="eliminar">Borrar</button>
            </div>

            <div class="nota">
                <span>Esta es una nota larga que ocupa más de una linea</span>
                <button class="eliminar">Borrar</button>
            </div>

            <div class="nota">
                <span>Otra nota de ejemplo</span>
                <button class="eliminar">Borrar</button>
            </div>

            <div class="nota">
                <span>Última nota de ejemplo</span>
                <button class="eliminar">Borrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yo veo un error al ejecutarlo: no existe un elemento con id "crearNota"